# definite integration of logarithmic function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^π\log(5-4\sin x)dx$$

I tried to proceed with this question using integration by parts but got stuck over $\int_0^π(\frac{-4x\cos x}{5}-4\sin x) dx$.

I also tried to proceed through changing $\cos x$ into the half-angle formula of $\tan \frac x2$ but that $\log$ thing doesn't allow me to make the substitution.

Comment: Taylor series __

Comment: I didn't get how to use Taylor series in this problem.

Comment: @KumarVivek he edited and added characters for mathematical formatting. Why are you against it?

Comment: @KumarVivek I only fixed some MathJax expressions. Actually, you have modified the question, you have just swap the sine and cosine functions.

Comment: We dont change any expression. Even if its wrong, we just format it

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have some mistakes from the start. Using integartion by parts
$$\int \ln(5-4\sin (x))\,dx=x \log (5-4 \sin (x))+4\int\frac{ x \cos (x)}{5-4 \sin (x)}\,dx$$
$$\int_0^\pi \ln(5-4\sin (x))\,dx=\pi  \log (5)+4\int_0^\pi\frac{ x \cos (x)}{5-4 \sin (x)}\,dx$$

The last integral is a pure nightmare (try it with [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bx+Cos%5Bx%5D%2F%285-4Sin%5Bx%5D%29%2Cx%5D)) but it can be evaluated.

By the way
$$\int_0^\pi \ln(5-4\sin (x))\,dx=2\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \ln(5-4\sin (x))\,dx$$ which could approximate (make a plot of it) as the area of the two approximate triangles that is to say $\sim \frac \pi 2 \ln(5) =2.53$ while numerical integration would give $2.41$.

Comment: the answer given in the book is 2πlog2 which doesn't match.

Comment: @KumarVivek. If we speak about the initial integral, the answer in the book is wrong.

Comment: will u please explain how to proceed with complex substitution in integrals.

Comment: @KumarVivek $2\pi\ln\left(2\right) \approx 4.3552$ while your proposed integration is $\approx 2.4063$ which shows that something is wrong with your question.